# how to resolve this error in paypal sandbox

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

PayPal Payment Standard method(Sandbox),

After doing all the setup in buyer account,

When the transaction time we need to retrieve the payment status(Success/Failure), with the help of these options, will get the payment status.

1) Instant Payment Notification (IPN)

2) Payment Data Transfer(PDT)

When i enable **Payment Data Transfer(PDT)** On.

while doing the transaction in paypal receive these error like this...

Rapids::Exception (N6Rapids5Tools13PimpExceptionE): Pimp RC: 3514

```
Failure log: Use of pimp_rc (4814), Use of pimp_rc (3013), Use of pimp_rc (4814), Use of pimp_rc (3174), Use of pimp_rc (14816), Use of pimp_rc (9449), Use of pimp_rc (9445), Use of pimp_rc (4814), Use of pimp_rc (3507), Use of pimp_rc (4001), Use of pimp_rc (4002), Use of pimp_rc (3778), Use of pimp_rc (4007), Use of pimp_rc (4020), Use of pimp_rc (7003), Use of pimp_rc (3583), Use of pimp_rc (3051), Use of pimp_rc (3001), Use of pimp_rc (3021), Use of pimp_rc (3242), Use of pimp_rc (3165), Use of pimp_rc (3101), Use of pimp_rc (3085), Use of pimp_rc (3209), Use of pimp_rc (3174), Use of pimp_rc (3043), Use of pimp_rc (3241), Use of pimp_rc (3082), Use of pimp_rc (3129), Use of pimp_rc (3567), Use of pimp_rc (3235), Use of pimp_rc (3236), Use of pimp_rc (3508), Use of pimp_rc (3507), Use of pimp_rc (3531), Use of pimp_rc (3514), Use of pimp_rc (3124), Use of pimp_rc (3047), Use of pimp_rc (3224), Use of pimp_rc (3093), Use of pimp_rc (3253), Use of pimp_rc (3254), Use of pimp_rc (3083), Use of pimp_rc (3137), Use of pimp_rc (3256), Use of pimp_rc (14268), Use of pimp_rc (14267), Use of pimp_rc (14266), Use of pimp_rc (14269), Use of pimp_rc (14264), Use of pimp_rc (14265), Use of pimp_rc (14244), Use of pimp_rc (3084), Use of pimp_rc (3254), Use of pimp_rc (3083), Use of pimp_rc (3137), Use of pimp_rc (3070), Use of pimp_rc (3141), Use of pimp_rc (3198), Use of pimp_rc (3011), Use of pimp_rc (10021), Use of pimp_rc (3199), Use of pimp_rc (3015), Use of pimp_rc (3014), Use of pimp_rc (3200), Use of pimp_rc (3257), Use of pimp_rc (3012), Use of pimp_rc (3141), Use of pimp_rc (3535), Use of pimp_rc (3504), Use of pimp_rc (10022), Use of pimp_rc (6702), Use of pimp_rc (3001), Use of pimp_rc (3120), Use of pimp_rc (3517), Use of pimp_rc (3531), Use of pimp_rc (3201), Use of pimp_rc (3803), Use of pimp_rc (6834), Use of pimp_rc (3807), Use of pimp_rc (3808), Use of pimp_rc (3810), Use of pimp_rc (3812), Use of pimp_rc (3809), Use of pimp_rc (3805), Use of pimp_rc (2002), Use of pimp_rc (3177), Use of pimp_rc (3051), Use of pimp_rc (3510), Use of pimp_rc (4003), Use of pimp_rc (3013), Use of pimp_rc (4011), Use of pimp_rc (3300), Use of pimp_rc (3286), Use of pimp_rc (6681), Use of pimp_rc (14605), Use of pimp_rc (10361), Use of pimp_rc (14353), Use of pimp_rc (14817), Use of pimp_rc (4002), Use of pimp_rc (2001), Use of pimp_rc (4001), Use of pimp_rc (11045), Use of pimp_rc (3593), Use of pimp_rc (4071), Use of pimp_rc (3514), Use of pimp_rc (4022), (rcf @ virtual int Merchant::PimpAutoSellerBLIImpl::seller_generate_transaction_token(ullong, PimpTransID&):406) , Use of pimp_rc (3514) Backtrace: PPException::PPException(String const&) Rapids::Tools::PimpException::PimpException() Rapids::BusinessBlocks::HostedPayments::get_synch_ipn_url(PayPalCommonWebAppContext const&, unsigned long long, String const&, String const&, String&, PimpTransaction const&, MiscUbiquityContainer&, TransactionUbiquityContainer&, String const&, unsigned long long) Rapids::BusinessBlocks::HostedPayments::get_synch_ipn_url(PayPalCommonWebAppContext const&, PimpXClick&, PimpTransaction const&, MiscUbiquityContainer&, TransactionUbiquityContainer&, unsigned long long) Rapids::Flows::HostedPayments::StateAutoreturnCheck::execute(Rapids::CGIVars const&) Rapids::DecoratedState::execute(Rapids::CGIVars const&) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::handle_execute(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Rapids::TransitionRegistry const&, Rapids::State*, String const&, String const&, unsigned long long) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::process_states(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::ProcessStates, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&, Rapids::TransitionEdge const*) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::flow_continue_from_interception(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::call_rapids(Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::RapidsFlowFactory const&, Riprap::DispatchAction const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::dispatch_loop(Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::DispatchAction&, Riprap::WebAppReturn&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::dispatch_wrapper(OutputStream&, Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, bool const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::entry_point(HTTPInterface&, Riprap::CGIVars&, OutputStream&, String const&, String const&) main

An error has occurred.

Return to the homepage
```

[image]

[image]

When i disable **Payment Data Transfer(PDT)** off. it seems working fine....

Comment: no code...this happen in the paypal sandbox itself... when i am doing the trasaction... (if i disable Payment Data Transfer(PDT) its working fine)

Comment: Oh my... those are internal PayPal error codes that should never be sent out to you. PayPal has crashed badly, sorry. Please contact PayPal customer support directly with this detailed error report and they will look in to the problem for you.

Comment: issue because of unverified merchant email.... if the merchant email is verified it seems fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is because of unverified merchant account..

[check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782836/how-can-i-verify-sandbox-merchant-account-in-paypal/31784418#31784418)

[image]

kindly check this image...