# How can I verify sandbox merchant account in PayPal?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating the **Paypal payment gateway standard** in my website. I have made all the setup configuration and the transaction goes through well, but the problem is that I can't verify the email.

1) [image]

[image]

Kindly suggest how can I verify the email in sandbox account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed/verified your email address `prasadraja07-facilitator@aol.com` in the backend.

In Future, it is recommended to create the sandbox accounts from [developer.paypal.com](https://developer.paypal.com/) where the created sandbox accounts

- would be already verified (if you have checked `Bank verified account` option as Yes)
- To confirm your email, check your developer.paypal.com dashboard and look into your email notifications where you see email confirmation link.

[image]